# Create an external reference between cells in different workbooks C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have Two Excel Files
abc.xlsx
  --Summary

xyz.xlsx
  --Summary

I want to give Reference of one cell from  abc.xlsx excel File to xyz.xlsx file

```
ws.Cells[1, 4].Formula = "('[abc.xlsx]Summary'!$D$36)";
```

But it is not working 
The issue is that Excel formulas linked to other workbooks doesn't update automatically (without opening the source) but when i open the source workbook it automatically update itself.

Can any one suggest a correct answer

I m using https://epplus.codeplex.com/

Thanks

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Comment: Formulas can't update without an instance of Excel to update them.  Excel files are not standalone.

Answer (score 1):

Formulas can't update without an instance of Excel to update them. Excel files are not standalone.

Comment: WheneverI opened excel file which is created with ePPlus it says that "the work book contain linksed to other Datasource.. if you update the Links excel will Retrive the Latest data" .. it should update when I click on Update button .. but it's not working .. but when I do the same thing without using ePPlus library it work's .. I m sure that the Code i has shared in my first post .. has something Wrong..

Comment: EPPlus has nothing to do with it.  Make sure that the path in the columns is correct and that the data in the other workbook has actually changed.  If you write to an Excel file without opening it in Excel, the formulas will not recalculate.  Period.

Comment: The column which i m referening  do the addition of columns =SUM(F26:F35)

Comment: Ok.  That formula will not update until Excel opens the file and updates it.

Comment: i just found in ePPlus documentation that : The formula parser does not support : References to external workbooks ..